# Chrome/Edge runs slow in F12 developers tools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Has anyone else seen F12 developers tool RUN SLOW, Very SLOW on Chrome/Microsoft Edge?

I tried it on FireFox and everything works fine when using F12.

Chrome version:  81.0.4044.129
Microsoft Edge version: Version 81.0.416.68 (Official build) (64-bit)

I reported it via chromium bug report. Just curious if anyone else is seeing this.

I removed a couple of extension and it still does it.

Comment: I've seen it happen when the page has many styles or custom variables. Anyway the question is too broad/vague and not answerable on StackOverflow without [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My co-worker figured it out.

https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/async-call-stack/

I needed to go to Options for F12 and check "Disable async stack traces".

Once that is checked, F12 developers tool works fine and there is log lag!

[image]

Thanks Brad!

Comment: Worked like a charm! ‍♂️

Comment: No effect. Just went through the trouble of upgrading my workstation to alleviate other performance issues, and now my screaming-fast laptop is tripping up... on the browser. What a joke.